# How do I know if this function is both One-to-One and "Onto?"

Tags: functions

I'm sure the question I have is probably rather simple, but I'm not 100% sure about it.

In class, we had this function:

$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R\times(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\})&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&\dfrac xy.\end{array}$$

From my understanding, the function is not one-to-one because there could occur a situation where you have different values which result in the same answer (i.e, $\frac{10}{1}=10$, $\frac{100}{10}=10$), but I'm not as certain when it comes to finding if it is "onto."

From my understanding, all values must be possible to be achieved if it were graphed (think of a parabola $g(x)=x^2-2$ where $g$ is a map from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$; all values below $-2$ aren't used, making it neither "onto" or one to one), but I'm not so sure about this one.

Am I thinking about this the right way?

Comment: Your example, to disprove injectivity, is correct and sufficient.  For surjectivity...well, pick a value, $c\in \mathbb R$.  Can you find $x,y$ such that $\frac xy=c$?  That's all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the reason why $f$ is not injective. And it is surjective because, for each $x\in\mathbb R$, $f(x,1)=x$.